# Coerce elements in xml/html document to data.frame

Tags: r, xml, rvest

Say you have a document in R in the following format:

```
<grp>
<elementx>
  <sub_a>a</sub_a>
  <sub_b>b</sub_b>
  <sub_c>c</sub_c>
</elementx>
<elementx>
  <sub_a>1</sub_a>
  <sub_b>2</sub_b>
  <sub_c>3</sub_c>
</elementx>
</grp>
```

What would be the most elegant way to coerce these to a `data.frame`, ie. equivalent to the following..?

```
data.frame(sub_a = c('a',1), sub_b = c('b',2), sub_c = c('c',3))
  sub_a sub_b sub_c
1     a     b     c
2     1     2     3
```

It's not an html table, but since all the elements share the same simple internal format we should be able to treat them just like a table..

Comment: Note elements of data.frame columns must hare same type. So the numbers in the columns will be cast to character type. I assume this is what you want? Did you try `xmlToDataFrame()`

Comment: As @dww mentions, your XML is a straightforward structure which can be handled with XML package's xmlToDataframe: `df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//elementx"))`

Comment: Thanks. I'm hitting an error `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmlToDataFrame’ for signature ‘"xml_nodeset"`.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/raw/LTfY3RZC

Comment: You are conflating packages. The rvest's `read_html()` output may not align to XML's `xmlParse()` which the object used in `xmlToDataframe()`. Consider using only XML for this straightforward need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With xml that is already in a simple structure such as this, it can easily be converted using `xmlToDataFrame()` from XML package as follows:

```
library(XML)

xmlstr <- 
"<grp>
  <elementx>
    <sub_a>a</sub_a>
    <sub_b>b</sub_b>
    <sub_c>c</sub_c>
  </elementx>
  <elementx>
    <sub_a>1</sub_a>
    <sub_b>2</sub_b>
    <sub_c>3</sub_c>
  </elementx>
</grp>"  

df <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlstr)
df
#  sub_a sub_b sub_c
#1     a     b     c
#2     1     2     3
```

If the xml is in a file, rather than a string, then you can use this:

```
xmlstr <- readLines("test.xml")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlstr)
```

If you want to get your xml directly from an http address, (as in the comment to your question) then this works

```
doc = readLines('https://www.gov.uk/government/announcements.atom?announcement_filter_option=statements&topics%5B%5D=transport')
df2 <- xmlToDataFrame(doc)
```

If you are dealing with very large xml files that are slow to convert this way, [this blog post](https://hopstat.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/faster-xml-conversion-to-data-frames/) describes  a faster function hosted on github that you could try: `require(devtools);  install_github("processVISION", "muschellij2")`